# Minecraft Eclipse Error: constrictor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I'm having trouble with the `super(i, Material.wood)` line. It says "constrictor call must be the fist statement in a constructor". I don't know what to do or what it means, so if you have an idea or want test it out and let me know how to fix it I'd much appreciate it!

**mod_new**

```
package net.minecraft.src;

public class mod_new extends BaseMod {

    public static Object ruby;

    public mod_new(int i, Material rock) {
        super(i, rock);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static final Block newblock = (new Ruby(243, null).setHardness(3F).setResistance(4F).setLightValue(1-0F).setUnlocalizedName("newblock"));
    public static final int blockID = 0;

    public void load() {
        Ruby ruby = null;
        ModLoader.registerBlock(ruby);

        ModLoader.addName(ruby, "ruby");
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(ruby, 1), new Object [] {"#", Character.valueOf('#'), Block.dirt});
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**mod_Ruby**

```
package net.minecraft.src;
import java.util.Random;

public class Ruby extends Block {

    protected Ruby(int par1, Material par2Material) {
        super(par1, par2Material);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void ruby (int i) {
         super(i, Material.wood); // exception here
    }

    public int idDropped(int i, Random random, int j) {
        return mod_new.blockID;
    }

    public int quantityDropped(Random random) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you notice anything else or need to know something. I have not made any changes to other Minecraft files such as `item.java`, except `modloder.java`.

Comment: That's not a constructor. `public Ruby(int i){...}` would be a constructor for example.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword seems  little bit off there.

`static` methods cannot invoke the `super(...)` constructor; only constructors can.

Following that auto-generated constructor stub, change your signature to:

```
public Ruby(int i) {
    super(i, Material.wood);
}
```

Comment: okay i fix that problem, thank you very much DerMike, now it just says "ModLoader 1.5.2 Initializing...
Failed to load mod from "mod_new.class"
Done."   Any ideas? -thanks

Comment: Nope, sorry. This doesn't look java'ish to me and I don't know Minecraft modding. Maybe ask another question. (And please mark my answer as 'Accepted' :-) )